# Android Studio dataSnapshot exists but nothing is getting printed Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm confused as to why this is not working and I have tried debugging it a lot and I have no idea why is this not working

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("dataSnapshot", "exists");
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("inside snapshot", "snapshot not null");
                    String name = snapshot1.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("user created", "snapshot not null");
                    try {
                        Log.d("name", name);
                        Log.d("decrypt", aes.Decrypt(name));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(EnterName.this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(EnterName.this, "logged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(EnterName.this,"doesnt exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the log that dataSnapshot exists but nothing after that. Firebase data is
[image: Firebase Data]

Anyone has any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. As a bonus, this will also enable the correct syntax highlighting for the code in your question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I see you have already updated the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening to just the `users/name` property, which means you get a snapshot with the key `name` and a string value `"check"`. A string value doesn't have any children, so `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` returns an empty list.

To print the value of your snapshot:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("dataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }
        ...
```